# EditText onClick() "indicator" color

Tags: android, android-edittext

I am currently trying to change the design of an EditText in Android Studio - specifically some colors. I was able to change the color of the cursor, the underline and the text, but not of the following object:

[image: The indicator]

This "indicator" appears if one clicks at previously entered text (e.g. changing position of the cursor).

My questions are:

(1) What is this "Indicator" called? (Sorry if this is a duplicate. It's hard to search for something I don't know the name of)

(2) How can I retrieve the drawable of it, so I can add a color filter?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on your `colorAccent`. Change your `colorAccent` code according to your choice and get edittext indicator same.

Comment: Most welcome If you like my answer please mark right.Happy coding:)

Comment: I will. Can't do it for another 5 minutes. No idea why they added this "You have to wait 10 minutes before you can accept an answer" thing :(

Comment: Thanks @MatthiasBö

Answer (score 2):

You need the change the accent color in your app's style.xml file. The style.xml resource file contains a style with the name "AppTheme" that are referenced from the app’s AndroidManifest.xml file to specify the app’s theme.

[image]

Set`android:colorAccent` to your desired color and you are good to go.